# Working with the jquery mobile popups

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, popup

I am building a webapp with jquery mobile. I want to do a basic popup like is shown over [here](http://jquerymobile.com/branches/popup-widget/docs/pages/popup/index.html).

But it is not working and it is also displaying the text on the screen.
Here is my HTML:

```
<div data-role="popup" id="basic" data-transition="pop">
    <p>I am a default popup</p>
</div>
```

And I have called it like this.

```
if (zalen.length > 0) {   
    $('#basic').popup();     
} else {
    $('#basic').popup();    
}
```

Can anybody help?

Comment: Are you getting any errors in your browser's console?

Comment: the problem can be related to css, have you tried: `$( "#basic" ).popup({
   opened: function() { alert('opened') }
});`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't follow the documentation correctly:

1) **The link** that opens the popup should have the attribute `data-rel="popup"`, and `href="#somePopup"`.

2) **The popup content** should have the attribute `data-role="popup"` along with the ID you specified in the `href` attribute for the link. (`id="somePopup"` for the element containing the popup content)

3) Then you can call it programmatically like you suggested, `$("#somePopup").popup();`

**Edit:** Aside from this problem that was fixed, it seems like @SySammy is correct; the popup widget is still in development and is not in the current release version.

Comment: Oké but the problem is, there is no link. It should come as an alert when something happens.

Comment: Indeed, so just skip the link step :)
You have the wrong attributes on your popup DIV - it should have `data-role="popup"` and the relevant ID.

Comment: Ok now I got this error in firebug $("#basic").popup is not a function
 

$('#basic').popup();

Comment: are you sure you included all of the JS files related? it should work. If you did include all the JS required, please post your code with the fix

Comment: For me it only works with `$("#somePopup").popup("open");`without "open" it just gets ignored

Answer (score 3):

If you have something like this:

```
<div data-role='page' id='page0'>


</div>
<div data-role='page' id='pag1'>


</div>
 <div data-role='popup' id='pop1'>

</div>
```

it will not work, the popup must be inside the page that calls it.

```
<div data-role='page' id='page0'>

   <div data-role='footer'></div>

   <div data-role='popup' id='pop1'>
   </div>
</div>
<div data-role='page' id='pag1'>


</div>
```

I don't know why is this, but I was having this kind of issue, and this was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Popups are still in development, you will need to wait until the next release or use [this plugin](http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-SimpleDialog/demos2/)

Answer (score 0):

Have you ensure javascript for jquery and jquery-mobile is included in order.

```
<head>
  <script src="js/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src="jquery.mobile/jquery.mobile-1.3.0-beta.1.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <div  data-role="popup" id="basic" data-transition="pop">
                  <p>I am a default popup</p>
      </div>
     <div onclick="javascript:onSuccess();" >Open Popup</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
 function onSuccess(){
      $('#basic').popup('open'); 
 }    
</script>

</body>
```

Comment: You are adding html elements inside the script tag, whats the propose?

Comment: sorry i already have edit that... refer this
[link](http://jsfiddle.net/zainozzaini/fL57M/)

Answer (score -1):

Try this one

```
<div  data-rel="popup" id="basic" data-transition="pop">
          <p>I am a default popup</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

It's was not stated in the documentation at the time this question was posed, that the HTML code of the popup must be inside `<div data-role="page"> ... </div>`. See: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/4891

Now, if you don't want to bother with these concepts and focus on your popup content, use my plugin https://stackoverflow.com/a/12092465/976827 - I've recommended this on another jQuery mobile popup() related question. Check the demo and code, it's easy to use.

**Demo and code** https://github.com/serbanghita/jQM-dynamic-popup

Comment: I'm just curious why this was down voted. I'm using it in production on a single page web app since jQM 1.2 alpha